# Iterate list of directories and sub-directories to run a specific command under each of them in windows

Tags: batch-file, iterator

I have a parent folder containing several child folders. I am trying to run a bat script that runs a specific operation under the child folders. But, I do not want the script to run in all of the child folders. I need to exclude a few from the list. This is what I have now:

```
pushd
for /D %%i in (<<path To Parent>>\*) do call :$myFunc "%%i"
popd
exit /B

:$myFunc
for %%g in ("Child2"
"Child3") do ( if /I "%1"=="%%~g" goto match )
echo current directory: %1
exit /B

:$match
echo matched directory
exit /B
```

In the `:$myFunc` subroutine, I can do a `cd %1` to enter that child directory and run my command then do a `cd` to come back to the parent folder. One thing I am trying to do before is to exclude the `:$myFunc` operation if the incoming folder is on my exclude list.

Folder tree:

```
ParentFolder
  Child1
  Child2
  Child3
  Child4
```

Given a sample folder structure like above, how can I not call `myFunc` when the for selects `Child2` and `Child3`.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: The line-break after `call` is a typo here, right? And you should change the comparison to `if /I "%~1"=="%%~g"`...

Comment: Yes, the line-break is a typo. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: @aschipfl it did not work :( I have updated the question with my latest script.

Comment: My comment was not a solution, just some syntax issues I spotted, sorry... anyway, you forgot the `~` in `"%~1"`... and let me suggest to use `pushd`/`popd` rather than `cd`...

Comment: You should be able to utilise, `FindStr` with at least its `/V` and possibly `/G` options to exclude those directories, directly within the `For` parentheses.

Comment: You are `goto`ing to the `:match` subroutine which actually doesn't exist. Did you mean `goto $match`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's certainly possible and can be done with the following code (lots of changes):

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Set which folders to exclude. This is changeable and NOT HARDCODED:
set exclude_folders="Child2" "Child3"

for /F %%A IN ('dir /B /AD "<path to parent>"') do (
    if "!exclude_folders:%%~nxA=!" == "%exclude_folders%" (call :$myFunc "%%A" "%%~fA")
)
exit /b %errorlevel%


:$myFunc
pushd "%~2"
rem Do your commands here; don't use pushd again!
popd
```

Note that the first argument is the folder name if it is located it in `%cd%`. Else, it is full path. The second argument is optional and more general, but I am sure you will need it!

I have changed the code as follows:

- Created a variable named `exclude_folders` to list here the folders you want to execute.
- Created a `for /F` loop to loop through a command, (`dir /B /AD`) to loop through all folders, avoid hidden ones!
- If the folder name (`%%~nxA`) [used `%%~nxA` because folder may contain a dot (`.`)] is excluded from the `exclude_folders` and the variable **changes** (in other words if string `foldername` exists in `exclude_folders`) this means that the folder is blacklisted and the `for` loop will start with the next line, since there is no command for `else`. If the opposite happens, `call` subroutine `$myFunc` with two arguments: `%%A` and `%%~fA`
- Do some command in `%~2` folder and return back to the loop.
- When the loop is finished, the script will `exit`.